# Zip images in directory

Tags: mac, osx-mountain-lion, zip

I have a directory of directories. Each directory contains ~100 images. I want to create a zip for each directory.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto the directory in a Terminal window and run the following:

```
find . -type d -depth 1 -exec zip -r {}.zip {} \;
```

- `find .`

  - searches the path
- `-type d`

  - only allows directories
- `-depth 1`

  - up to a depth of one
- `-exec <cmd> {} \;`

  - execute `cmd` for each result `{}` you find

And finally `zip -r <dest> <src>` which zips the directories recursively.

Comment: Didn't work. It produced the zips but they're all less than 1kb.

Comment: Updated the answer to add the recursive option.